# Selecting multiple from @Html.ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added @Html.ListBoxFor i am able to bind it properly but unable to get multiple selected items after submit. Am i missing something ?

```
  // Below is the code for binding

  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var cities = So.BL.City.GetCities();

        SelectList cityList = new SelectList(cities, "Id", "Name", cityId);
        TempData["Cities"] = cityList;

        return View("Create");
    }


 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Keywords,Cities")] So.Entities.Approval filter)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


        }
        return View(filter);
    }
```

Below is the view file code. I dont have a view model just entities

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cities:
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       @* <td>
              @Html.DropDownList("Cities", (SelectList)TempData["Cities"])    
        </td>*@
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(TempData["Cities"] as MultiSelectList, "Value","Text",new { style = "width:250px" })))


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Keywords)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Keywords)

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What type is `model.Id`?

Comment: entity @model So.Entities.FBApprovalFilter

Comment: Sorry, this did not make a lot of sense to me. Let's be more precise - what type if property `Id`? Is it a list of some primitives, e.g. int or string? Or just an int? For multiple selection you need a list to receive all selected values

Comment: Well, suppose user selects multiple values. Hence multiple ints are posted. How is single int field going to accommodate them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have changed the ID property to typeof `int[]` as per the comments, you still have problems, the main one being that your POST method has

```
 [Bind(Include="Keywords,Cities")]
```

which excludes binding of the `ID` property so it will always be null on post back. When ever you use the `[Bind]` attribute you should reconsider what you doing and use a view model to display/edit just the properties you want, including a property for the `SelectList`.

You also have some pointless code in the `@Html.ListBoxFor()` method. `TempData["Cities"]` is already a `SelectList` so `new SelectList(TempData["Cities"] as MultiSelectList, "Value","Text"` is converting the `SelectList` to a `MultiSelectList` and then creating a new `SelectList` form it. All you need is

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ID, (SelectList)TempData["Cities"], new { style = "width:250px" })
```

In addition, the 3rd parameter in this

```
SelectList cityList = new SelectList(cities, "Id", "Name", cityId);
```

is not required (not sure where you declared `cityId` because as it is, your code does not compile). The `ListBoxFor()` method selects the options based on the value of your `ID` property, and ignores the `selectedValue` parameter in the `SelectList` constructor.

Finally, in your POST method, if the model is not valid you return the view. You need to reassign the value of `TempData["Cities"]` or this will be `null` in the view and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrei is suggesting, you need to bind the selected value to an array type.

Front End:

```
    <div class="DualListBoxDIV">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RelatedNewsArticlesSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.AssignedRelatedNewsArticles, "Value", "Text", Model.RelatedNewsArticlesSelected), new { @class = "SelectedBox", Size = 10 })
    </div>
```

Back End:

```
    public string[] RelatedNewsArticlesSelected { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AssignedRelatedNewsArticles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UnassignedRelatedNewsArticles { get; set; }
```

Comment: it is necessary to take ViewModel ?

Comment: Yours should be ok, just the model.Id needs to be a int[] instead of just int

Comment: i understood what you explained. 
i have changed below code, still on submit i am getting null values 
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Ids, new SelectList(TempData["Cities"] as MultiSelectList, "Value","Text",new { style = "width:250px" })))

Comment: Would it be possible to create a model class for your page? 

That's the only different I notice between our pages